# CakePhp cakesession not working with cake php debug kit

Tags: cakephp-2.2

I implement cakephp debugkit plugin in my project.
    In my appcontroller.php file i add

```
 var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Paginator', 'Js', 'Session'); 
 public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

 and in before filter i implement 
function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->Session->check('GlobalFields')==false) {
    $this->Session->write('GlobalFields.tbl_assets.template_information_global', '');
    $this->Session->write('GlobalFields.tbl_assets.hilitelibrary', '');
    $this->Session->write('GlobalFields.tbl_assets.hilitesortedby', '');
    $this->Session->write('GlobalFields.tbl_assets.sc_url_prefix', '');
    }
}
   but it showing error 
   Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object.
   and i check that debug($this->Session) returns null.

 if i remove public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar'); then its run correctly.
 but i want to implement that debugkit with session.
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what happens here is that by setting:

```
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
```

you are overriding the default value of that which includes the [SessionComponent](http://api22.cakephp.org/class/session-component). 
You are attaching the [SessionHelper](http://api22.cakephp.org/class/session-helper) in the `$helpers` variable but those two classes are different - the first one (the component) allows you do interact with session data within the Controller and the second one (the helper) is used in your views.

So the solution to your issue is setting:

```
public $components = array('Session','DebugKit.Toolbar');
```

Also if you were using any other components globally you should add them there too.